# Need workaround to make WebStorm's autocompletion capable to resolve third party module methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

Almost for all third-party modules WebStorm's autocomplition cannot resolve methods/fields. Under autocompletion I mean also all intellisense-like features.
For example:

```
var async = require('async');
async.series() //WebStorm's tooltip says: Unresolved function or method series()
```

At the same time it resolves

```
async.exports.series().
```

But this leads to runtime error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'series' of undefined
```

For my own modules I've found workaround. If I do in the module:

```
var myModule = module.exports;
myModule.someMethod = function(){
...
}
```

Then autocomplition for someMethod works fine.

Regarding all of above I have a bunch of questions.
1. Why the ide fails to resolve async.series()?
2. Why async.exports.series() leads to runtime error?
3. How to make autocomplition work?

WebStorm 5.0.4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use new as follows:

```
var async = new require('async');
```

Comment: Thanks this works... 1. I would like to understand how it appeases WebStorm. 2. If this might have bad side effects for normal node.js use.

Answer (score 18):

Go to Settings -> JavaScript -> Libraries -> Check "Node.js Globals"

Comment: I have this setting selected, but I'm still seeing the problem.  Any more clues?

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

New WebStorm v7 has ability to define Typescript community stubs for popular modules. This partially solves the problem with autocompletion and IDE warnings.

For less popular modules I prefer to use this ugly cheat:

```
//noinspection ConstantConditionalExpressionJS,JSPotentiallyInvalidConstructorUsage
var async = false ? new require('async') : require('async');
```

However, this doesn't solves the problem, when property been attached to module by some algorithm (for example iterating filesystem). For small and unpopular modules it is a rare case.

BTW, async has already typescript stub in git@github.com:borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped.git repository.

Comment: Strange, but things like `var connect = require('connect')||'';` work for me too.